# Работа с датами в php-laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем ку, такая задачка, есть **дата начала** и **дата окончания**, **которую задает клиент** и нужна такая проверка, допустим  **клиент задал такую дату начала Y.m.d  "12.08.2022"**,  то **дата окончания должна быть, либо плюс 3 месяца, либо 6, либо 9, либо 12, либо 24 месяца ровно**, т.е **если дата окончания будет 3 месяца и один день уже ошибка** и так с каждым месяцем, должно быть ровно, не половина, не день, только ровные месяца, не на день больше, не на половину дня, доступные месяца окончания я указал, типо 3 месяца, минус один день, 6 месяцев минус один день, вот так надо, есть много способов манипуляции с date, но я логически не могу понять, как это реализовать, спасибо заранее!

```
   public function checkDaysBetween($data)
{
    $end = strtotime($data['agrEnd']);
    if (strtotime(date('d.m.Y', strtotime($data['agrBeg'] . '+3 months'))) == $end || strtotime(date('d.m.Y', strtotime($data['agrBeg'] . '+4 months'))) == $end) {

        return ['code' => 200];
    }
    return [
        'code' => 422,
        'error' => 'Допустимо создавать договор, только на следующие периоды времени: 3 месяца, 6 месяцев, 9 месяцев, 12 месяцев, 24 месяца',
    ];
}
```

вот мое решение, оно сработало

Comment: общий класс https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php   и методы либо add  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php  либо modify  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php    например спокойно можно будет написать `->modify('+3 month');`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но если 3 месяца и один день, должно кидать ошибку, ->modify('+3 month'); это вы ведь гвоздем прибиваете и какую человек бы не выбрал дату окончания, она у него всегда будет плюс 3 месяца?

Comment: ну тебе же это и надо....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский он будет сам вбивать дату окончания и может сделать 3 месяца и 2 дня, а может 6 месяцев и 1 день, моя задача кинуть ошибку и сказать, либо 3 месяца ровно, либо 6 мес, либо пока, как-то так)

Comment: Ну ты возьми **его дату** и сравни с той, что необходима (как сделать необходимую - написано выше). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    только важно помнить что даты надо сравнивать в формате `YYYY-mm-dd` иначе не получится. либо через strtotime